# Что означает item?

Tags: python

```
chars = [ 'A' ,'B' , 'C' ]

print('\nElements:\t' , end = ' ' )
for item in chars :
    print( item , end = ' ' )
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, как это работает.
Я вообще не понимаю, что значит "item", и откуда оно вообще взялось, этого элемента ведь нет в списке. Эта какая-то функция языка?

Comment: https://younglinux.info/python/for.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`item` - это переменная, в которой на каждой итерации оказывается элемент списка (`list`) `chars`.

`for item in chars` - цикл по элементам массива `chars` (1-ая итерация - `item='A'`, 2-ая итерация - `item='B'` и тд. )

`print` - функция вывода на экран, которая на каждой итерации будет выводить один элемент списка (`item`) и пробел за ним (тут указан `end=' '`, по умолчанию `end='\n'`)

В результате выполнения кода будет выведено:

```
Elements: A B C
```